# jquery multi-select popup not show

Tags: css, multi-select

I use this [jQuery plugin](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select) for multi-select . but when i click on select box popup window not show perfectly and i think this is because css style of parent div .

```
 <div class="input_line" style="position: relative;">
                  <label class="e1m">Lenght?</label>
                  <div class="input_box" >
                      <div class="icon down_icon"></div>
                      <select class="inputy-wide" name="size" id="size" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                          <option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

this is Css style of parent div .

```
.input_line{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
.input_line label{
    font: 0.9em bkoodakbold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    color:#000000;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.input_line .input_box{
    width: 100%;
    background: #EEEEF3;
    border-radius:25px;
    height: 50px;   
}
```

and when click on select box like this:

[image]

how i can fix this style???

Comment: Please update the image of what does it look like. Couldnt see complete image. Also update the Jquery code for plugin init

Comment: this is full of image like this image only part of select show

Comment: There are multiple issues  but for now increase the `height: 50px;` to greater value in `.input_line .input_box`